# Mono for Droid: how to plot route

Tags: dictionary, xamarin.android, routes

I am working on Mono for Android App and want to show a route map between two points. I implemented their [Xamarin.Android Map API](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location) to get the current location.

I couldn't get how to plot a route from current location to destination. Is there any library or framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xamarin.Android Map API is based on *Google Maps Android v1 API* which is deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. If you *really, really* want to implement Google Maps I would recommend looking at the [Xamarin Maps and Location Demo v2](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2) which uses [Google Maps Android v2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). However drawing a route is still not an easy task - you can use the [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to obtain a polyline and use it to draw a shape on the map [as described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#geodesic_segments) (BTW notice the limitations of Direction API free usage).

I suggest a different approach. If your ok with using Open Street Maps I would definitely go for [OSM Droid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) library along with [OSM Bonus Pack](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) which does all the magic for you. Take a look at [Xamarin OSM Droid Binding sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/OsmDroidBindingExample). To include the Bonus Pack you can add its JAR to the Osm Droid Binding solution and fix two visibility issues by adding to Metadata.xml:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.osmdroid.bonuspack.routing']/class[@name='RoadLink']" name="visibility">public</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays']/class[@name='MapEventsOverlay']/method[@name='draw']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Having this set up there is a very nice Road Manager that will plot a route for us. Below is a sample code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private IMapController _mapController;
    private MapView _mapView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _mapView = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.mapview);
        _mapView.SetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource);
        _mapView.SetMultiTouchControls(true);

        _mapController = _mapView.Controller;

        RoadManager roadManager = new MapQuestRoadManager();

        JavaList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new JavaList<GeoPoint>();
        waypoints.Add(new GeoPoint(51.776625, 19.454834)); //start point
        waypoints.Add(new GeoPoint(51.770839, 19.464962)); //end point
        Road road = roadManager.GetRoad(waypoints);

        PathOverlay roadOverlay = RoadManager.BuildRoadOverlay(road, _mapView.Context);
        _mapView.Overlays.Add(roadOverlay);
        _mapView.Invalidate();

    }
}
```

More tutorials on this topic are located [here](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1).

Comment: You can also implement the drawing path between two points by using Polylines and Google direction api, check this http://www.appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/08/draw-path-between-two-location-in.html